# Unit Test doesnt prevent running any of the transactional code in unit tests

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

U've add the decorator @Transactionnal in my service method, all works fine, i follewed this documentation [Typeorm Transactional](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm-transactional)
My project works perfectly, also e2e tests, but coming to unit test the @Transactionnal seems to not be disabled at all.
My application is running with nestJs and Jest for UT.

this is my Unit Test ::

```
    describe('PctConfigService', () => {
        let pctService: PctConfigService;
        let pctConfigRepository: DeepMocked<PctConfigRepository>;
        let mapper: DeepMocked<PctConfigMapper>;
    
    
    
        beforeAll(async () => {
    

            jest.mock('typeorm-transactional', () => ({
  Transactional: () => () => ({}),
}));
           
            const app: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
                providers: [{
                    provide: PctConfigRepository,
                    useValue: createMock<PctConfigRepository>()
                    },
                    {
                        provide: getMapperToken(),
                        useValue: createMock<Mapper>(),
                    },
                PctConfigService]
            }).compile();
    
            pctConfigRepository = app.get(PctConfigRepository);
            mapper = app.get(getMapperToken());
            pctService = app.get<PctConfigService>(PctConfigService);
    
        });
    
        describe('Pct config service actions', () => {
    
            it('should throw exception', async () => {
                const pctconfig: PctConfig =
                    {
                        id: 123,
                        countryCode: 'FR',
                        endDate: null,
                        roleCode: 'CA_ICS_HBE',
                        startDate: new Date(),
                        coefficients: buildCoefficients(),
                        creationDate: null
                    };
    
                pctService.updatePctConfig(123,pctconfig);
            });
    
           
    
        });
    });
```

My service method is like this ::

```
@Injectable()
export class PctConfigService {
@Transactional()
async updatePctConfig(id: number, pctConfig: PctConfig): Promise<void> {
    //code
}
}
```

when i run my test ::  `npm run test`  and test in package.json is `"jest"`

i got this error ::

```
"Error: No CLS namespace defined in your app ... please call initializeTransactionalContext() before application start."
```

My question is how could i disable @Transactionnal in Unit Test only ?
it seems like "jest.mock('typeorm-transactional'" doesnt prevent transactional to be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed and the solution is to put the jest mock before start the "describe" block.

```
            jest.mock('typeorm-transactional', () => ({
  Transactional: () => () => ({}),
}));
    describe('PctConfigService', () => {});
```